# How can Zapier support Dropbox when Dropbox doesn't support Webhooks?

Tags: dropbox, webhooks, zapier

To the best of my knowledge [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) basically uses [Webhooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) to link services to eachother. One of the supported services is [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). However Dropbox (still) doesn't support webhooks. (i.e: Dropbox can't signal that a file has, say, updated or changed, to a arbitrary webhook endpoint of choice) .

So how then does Zapier support Dropbox? Does it do longpolling or something?

Comment: Dropbox now offers webhooks https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/90/announcing-dropbox-webhooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to ask them, but I would assume they poll the [`/delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta) API.

Comment: I can't comment on the specific implementation, but yes, in general if an API doesn't offer webhooks Zapier polls some other 'recently updated' endpoint and finds new items in that way.